# How do I get input[type=text] to line up with a Button?

Tags: html, css

I want the button and the text to line up. I've used vertical align but it doesn't seem to be working. (So the button is centered with the input box)

Here is HTML:

```
<div class="elegantaeronamefinder"> 


<div>
    <input type="text" id="search_name" name="search_name" />
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="GO" id="search_button" name="search_button" />
</div> 

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.elegantaeronamefinder{
  width: 800px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background:#F2F7FA;/*#DDF0F8;*/ 
  padding: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
  min-height: 120px; /*make additional service box bigger*/
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
  color: #666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}



.elegantaeronamefinder input[type="text"], .elegant-aeronamefinder textarea {
  color: #888;
  width:250px;
  padding: 5px 4px 0px 5px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #CEE2E7;
  background: #FBFBFB;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2);
  font: 200 20px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  vertical-align: middle; /*added in to align*/

 }      
.elegantaeronamefinder .button{
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
  background: #44B6F5;
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight:bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 5px;

 }
```

Here is demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/5CN67/2/

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Try changing margin-bottom to 7px for .elegantaeronamefinder .button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way would be to remove the margin settings from the rule `.elegantaeronamefinder .button`

```
.elegantaeronamefinder .button{
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    background: #44B6F5;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/5CN67/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can remove vertical-align and make bigger height of input, like this

```
.elegantaeronamefinder input[type="text"], .elegant-aeronamefinder textarea {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FBFBFB;
  border: 1px solid #CEE2E7;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2) inset;
  color: #888888;
  font: 200 20px/20px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 6px;
  outline: 0 none;
  padding: 5px 4px 0 5px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5CN67/9/

Also, you can remove `margin` from `.elegantaeronamefinder .button{}` and input will be on level of the middle of button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table` + `display: table-cell` + `vertical-align: middle`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CN67/10/)

HTML:

```
<div class="elegantaeronamefinder">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="search_name" name="search_name" />
        <input type="submit" class="button" value="GO" id="search_button" name="search_button" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.elegantaeronamefinder {
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background:#F2F7FA;
    /*#DDF0F8;*/
    padding: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
    min-height: 120px;
    /*make additional service box bigger*/
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
    color: #666;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}

.elegantaeronamefinder input[type="text"], .elegant-aeronamefinder textarea {
    color: #888;
    width:250px;
    padding: 5px 4px 0px 5px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CEE2E7;
    background: #FBFBFB;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2);
    font: 200 20px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*added in to align*/
}

.elegantaeronamefinder .button {
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    background: #44B6F5;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*added in to align*/
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! Although first method does exactly what I want

Answer (score 0):

You have 'messed up' the vertical alignment due to the additional margin declarations on the `.button` class.

If you remove them they align:

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/5CN67/12/)

**CSS**

```
.elegantaeronamefinder{
    width: 800px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    background:#F2F7FA;/*#DDF0F8;*/ 
    padding: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
    min-height: 120px; /*make additional service box bigger*/
    font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #868686;
    color: #666;


    border-collapse: collapse;
}



.elegantaeronamefinder input[type="text"],
.elegant-aeronamefinder textarea {
    color: #888;
    width:250px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 6px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #CEE2E7;
    background: #FBFBFB;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2);
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 2px rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.2);
    font: 200 20px/20px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    vertical-align: middle; /*added in to align*/

}

.elegantaeronamefinder .button{
    padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px;
    background: #44B6F5;
    border: none;
    color: #FFF;
    font-weight:bold;

}
```